# What does this mean in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database

I just installed MongoDB. I dont' have replication. All I turned on was auth in the config file. And I configured that properly.

It mostly works, but at random times, it "hangs", and it causes my CPU to jump to LOAD 4.0 when I do "top".

When I view message log, I See a lot of this:

```
[DataFileSync] flushing mmap took 0ms for 5 files
[DataFileSync] flushing mmap took 0ms for 5 files
[DataFileSync] flushing mmap took 0ms for 5 files
```

It's weird because it just hangs and nothing happens. These messages keep appearing, and the "accepted connection" does not appear anymore. I don't have replication on, and I didn't configure the mongo with any settings except auth.

Well, Mongo did crash once and I did a "sudo reboot" one time, while mongo was still runningl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sync looks pretty normal and only took 0ms ...

That said, MongoDB does have database level locking, so it would "hang" your whole database if some operation caused a lock (like a long query, building a big index, etc.)

I'd shutdown your database and run a [repair](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair).

You can run [validate](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair#DurabilityandRepair-ValidateCommand) first ... to see if it finds anything ...

```
> db.mycollection.validate();
```

It might be that there is a error in your data files caused by the unclean shutdown you mentioned ... and it's getting hung up on those errors.

```
$ ./mongod --repair
```

You can also run the repair "live" if you don't have too much load.

```
> db.repairDatabase();
```

You could also try and anylise the results of [mongostat](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongostat) ...

Comment: I did all of those, but it still spikes randomly.  

 510 syslog    20   0 38272 5268  988 S 51.5  0.9   0:31.80 rsyslogd                       
 
1549 mongodb   20   0  910m  38m  36m R 46.9  6.5   1:06.52 mongod

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB uses memory mapped files; changes to data are occasionally flushed from RAM to disk. This would be the map flushes you are seeing.

Comment: But why is it hanging, and causing my CPU to spike to 4.0? And all I see are those maps getting logged into the log file. I don't see anything else in the log file when this happens

Answer (score 0):

By default mongodb will flush the changes to disk every 60 seconds.  It should not be hung up during that time though.

What version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: I am using: MongoDB shell version: 1.6.5

Comment: Also, rsyslogd  spikes to 99% as well as mongod